# El expression or logic in Spring @Scheduled annotation for cron expression

Tags: spring, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE version and have some scheduled tasks that are annotated with @Scheduled, e.g. @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 15 * * 2") *every tuesday at 15:00*

I need more fine grained control on the cron expression to make it run for example:

- Mondays of every second and last week of month
- First monday of every month

How can I achieve this?

Perhaps with some EL expression that evaluates to a method in the same bean that returns desired cron expression as string?

Or maybe there already is some way of introducing such logic in the cron expression?

I tried to find some information for either solution with no luck, so I'd appreciate a good pointer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps with some EL expression that evaluates to a method in the same bean that returns desired cron expression as string?

If your main problem is that you want to avoid hard-coding the cron, then you can get it from properties file like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${my-schedule}")
```

where *my-schedule* is name of the key in the properties file:

```
my-schedule=0 0 15 * * 2
```